# how to highlight the currently playing audio when clicking on NEXT button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the current playing audio to highlight in the playlist when clicking the Next and Previous buttons, Right now it only highlight when clicking on the audio track.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="working_files/styles.css" title="Default" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="working_files/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player">
  <a href="#" class="audio prev"><span>Prev</span></a>
 <audio controls></audio>
  <a href="#" class="audio next"><span>Next</span></a>
  <br><span class="audio name"></span>
</div>
<div id="list">
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="AmericanToad_Call"><span active>1. American Toad Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="Bullfrog_Call"><span class="sound">2. Bullfrog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="CopesGrayTreefrog_Call"><span class="sound">3. Treefrog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="CricketFrog_Call"><span class="sound">4. Cricket Frog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="EasternGrayTreefrog_Call"><span class="sound">5. EasternGray Treefrog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="FowlersToad_Call"><span class="sound">6. Fowlers Toad Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="GreenFrog_Call"><span class="sound">7. Green Frog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="NorthernLeopardFrog_Call"><span class="sound">8. Northern Leopard Frog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="PickeralFrog_Call"><span class="sound">9. Pickeral Frog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="PlainsLeopardFrog_Call"><span class="sound">10. Plains Leopard Frog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="SpringPeeper_Call"><span class="sound">11. Spring Peeper Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="WesternChorusFrog_Call"><span class="sound">12. Western Chorus Frog Call</span></a></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="audio play" data-frogsong-id="WoodFrog_Call"><span class="sound">13. Wood Frog Call</span></a></p>
</div>
<script>
  $('span').on('click', function() {
  $('span').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
window.Formaweb = window.Formaweb || {};
window.Formaweb.Player = function() {
  'use strict';
  var audio;
  var playlist;
  var len;
  var current;
  init();
  function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio')[0];
    playlist = [
      {name: '1. American Toad Call', path: 'frog_sounds/AmericanToad_Call.mp3', id: 'AmericanToad_Call'},
      {name: '2. Bullfrog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/Bullfrog_Call.mp3', id: 'Bullfrog_Call'},
      {name: '3. Treefrog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/CopesGrayTreefrog_Call.mp3', id: 'CopesGrayTreefrog_Call'},
      {name: '4. Cricket Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/CricketFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'CricketFrog_Call'},
      {name: '5. EasternGray Treefrog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/EasternGrayTreefrog_Call.mp3', id: 'EasternGrayTreefrog_Call'},
      {name: '6. Fowlers Toad Call', path: 'frog_sounds/FowlersToad_Call.mp3', id: 'FowlersToad_Call'},
      {name: '7. Green Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/GreenFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'GreenFrog_Call'},
      {name: '8. Northern Leopard Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/NorthernLeopardFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'NorthernLeopardFrog_Call'},
      {name: '9. Pickeral Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/PickeralFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'PickeralFrog_Call'},
      {name: '10. Plains Leopard Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/PlainsLeopardFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'PlainsLeopardFrog_Call'},
      {name: '11. Spring Peeper Call', path: 'frog_sounds/SpringPeeper_Call.mp3', id: 'SpringPeeper_Call'},
      {name: '12. Western Chorus Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/WesternChorusFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'WesternChorusFrog_Call'},
      {name: '13. Wood Frog Call', path: 'frog_sounds/WoodFrog_Call.mp3', id: 'WoodFrog_Call'},
    ];

    len = playlist.length - 1;
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
    run(playlist[0], audio);
      next();
    });
    $('.audio.next').on('click', function(){
      next();
      run(playlist[current], audio);

      return false;
    });
    $('.audio.prev').on('click', function(){
      prev();
      run(playlist[current], audio);

      return false;
    });

    $('.audio.play').on('click', function(){
      var frogsong_id = $(this).attr('data-frogsong-id');

      if(frogsong_id != undefined){
        playById(frogsong_id);
      }

      return false;
    });
  }
  function run(frogsong, player) {
  $('.audio.name').text(frogsong.name);
  player.src = frogsong.path;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
function next(){
current++;
if(current > len) current = 0;
  }

  function prev(){
    current--;
    if(current < 0) current = 0;
  }

function playById(id){
    var playlist_id = undefined;

    $.each(playlist, function(index, value){
      if(value.id == id){
        playlist_id = index;
      }
    });

    if(playlist_id != undefined){
      current = playlist_id;
      run(playlist[current], audio);
    }
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
var player = window.Formaweb.Player(); 
});
```

```
#player {
  text-align: center;
  background:#e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 400px;
  padding:10px;
}
#player a {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: #000 2px solid;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000
}
#player span {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
audio {
  width: 300px;
  height: 55px;
}

#list {
  width: 422px;
}

#list span {
color: #000000;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
background: #c1c1c1;
display: block;
border: 1px solid;
padding:5px;
}

#list span.active {
  background: #736e69;
}

#list a:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

div p {
  margin:0;
    }

div a {
  text-decoration:none;
  }
```

How to get the current playing audio to highlight in the playlist when clicking the Next and Previous buttons, any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query selector which matches the data-frogsong-id and fetch then the children (which is the span element you want to get) and put the highlight class on it.

```
$('span').removeClass('active');
$('a[data-frogsong-id=' + playlist[current].id + ']').children().addClass ('active')
```

You can put this in the run method so you don't have to take care about the next and prev buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the issue.

Comment: @Ben You're welcome. Would be nice if you could hit the hook next to answer in order to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: just did. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi All. How to disable autoplay in IE in the code mentioned above? It's fine in Chrome.